# How to stop svchost.exe from consuming internet data?

Tags: svchost

What is svchost? When I’m connected to the internet svchost.exe consumes internet data for at least 15 minutes. Why is that happening? How to stop svchost.exe from consuming so much internet data?

Comment: The svchost process is harmless.  Why would you stop a system process from consuming data it needs?

Comment: @Ramhound, that is an overgeneralization. There are plenty of legitimate reasons to want to restrict services loaded within an SCVHosts process from accessing the internet, especially on Win10+.

Comment: @FrankThomas - We will have to agree to disagree.  There is nothing new about the services that run on Windows 10 or the data transmitted by its services.

Answer (score 1):

svchost.exe is doing what it is designed to do, servicing applications on your Windows machine (including networking).  To read more

- [What is svchost.exe And Why Is It Running?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/?PageSpeed=noscript)
- [What is svchost.exe?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe#1TC=windows-7)
- [How to Fix Svchost.exe High CPU Usage](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-fix-svchostexe-errors-and-problems-with-high-cpu-usage/)